# WCF autogenerate FaultContracts

Tags: wcf, faultcontract

We have many WCF services, we have not been using contract first. So now we have a lot of code that throws exceptions, that are not specified in the FaultContracts.

Other than manually inspecting the code. Is there a way to generate FaultContracts or at least get a warning when a FaultContract is missing?

Answer (score -1):

The Microsoft Enterprise Library Exception Handling Block has a feature which allows exceptions to be declaratively mapped to faults at the service boundary level.  This means that you don't have to explicitly raise the faults yourself; they will be created for you by the block when an exception reaches a service boundary.  See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd139900.aspx) for more details.

However this won't help you identify service operations which are missing fault contracts.  I'm not aware of a tool which can do this, so you may have to write your own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this would still require me to manually specify all the fault contracts, unless I have misunderstood something.

Comment: @Shiraz: Yes, that's correct.  I'm not aware of a tool that will analyse code coverage for fault contracts.  It's probably something you would have to write yourself using reflection.